# Why does SE hide the "stellar-dynamics" tag from us when we type "stella..." and leave a blank spot instead? ("stellar..." behaves differently)

Tags: support, tags, specific-tag, tagging, user-interface

When looking for the [stellar-dynamics](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stellar-dynamics) tag in the autocomplete box after [stellar-astrophysics](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stellar-astrophysics) had been selected, the suggested tags *concealed it from me* for "stell..." and "stella...", choosing instead to leave a blank space.

Only when "stellar..." was entered did it appear, seemingly because "constellation" was now not an option.

Is the withholding of this tag from visibility, and instead leaving a blank spot:

1. "by design"?
2. the most desirable behavior?
3. workaround-able?

---

[image: typing "stell..." in tags]

[image: typing "stella..." in tags]

Third time's a charm:

[image: typing "stellar..." in tags]

Comment: potentially related in Space SE meta: [I don't understand why - by design - “ion-thruster” tag remains hidden when I start typing “ion…”](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/766/12102)

Comment: From a support perspective, it seems the answer to this is roughly the same as the answer to your question over at Space SE. It's prioritizing tags with higher usage that match (regardless of how close of a match they are). I don't think there's room for a better support answer. Since your problem spans two sites, it may be time for a feature request over at Meta SE.

Comment: @called2voyage yes perhaps the time as come, I'm less scared of the main meta these days :-)

Comment: My question is about the "hiding" rather than the order of prioritization. I'll have to figure out how to ask in a positive way, perhaps just ask about how the algorithm works exactly, mentioning that I got interested because some tags didn't appear as I'd initially expected they should. I'm not sure I'm up to suggesting that something be changed unless I can make a really good case for it. Perhaps I can assemble more examples. I'll give it some thought.

Comment: But the hiding is already addressed at your linked discussion. It's because under certain conditions the SE tag suggestions only shows the top five results: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273448/why-isnt-the-tag-autocompletion-suggesting-6-tags-while-they-are-at-least-6-ava

Comment: @called2voyage okay I'll "dig in" tomorrow and see if I can wrap my head around it.